# 'failed to lookup address information' error is displayed on executing selenium test using Gecko driver on Mac OS

Tags: java, macos, selenium, firefox, geckodriver

I am having tuff time on executing Selenium test in Mac OS using Gecko driver. I am using Firefox 56.

Here is the code which i have used to initialize web driver.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/Users/<username>/Documents/Tools/geckodriver");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.firefox();         
capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
```

Now, when i execute a test, it seems Gecko driver is initialized but below mentioned error is displayed and the browser is not being initialized.

```
1507662170977   geckodriver INFO    geckodriver 0.19.0
1507662170983   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:42748
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeClass initializeDriver
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: failed to lookup address information: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
Build info: version: '3.6.0', revision: '6fbf3ec767', time: '2017-09-27T15:28:36.4Z'
System info: host: '<username>s-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: '192.168.1.2', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.12.6', java.version: '1.8.0_144'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
remote stacktrace: stack backtrace:
   0:        0x10d96ca8e - backtrace::backtrace::trace::h69682bcb53decaf6
   1:        0x10d96cacc - backtrace::capture::Backtrace::new::hdc9d731a957304a6
   2:        0x10d8ce8e3 - webdriver::error::WebDriverError::new::h4c6ae7c4aac049c6
   3:        0x10d8cf352 - _$LT$webdriver..error..WebDriverError$u20$as$u20$core..convert..From$LT$std..io..error..Error$GT$$GT$::from::ha068e680ab4e1954
   4:        0x10d8a221e - geckodriver::marionette::MarionetteHandler::create_connection::hc09196342b760e35
   5:        0x10d8847d4 - _$LT$webdriver..server..Dispatcher$LT$T$C$$u20$U$GT$$GT$::run::hfda25a6dc0b512aa
   6:        0x10d85c645 - std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_begin_short_backtrace::h95009c1d3a320838
   7:        0x10d86411d - std::panicking::try::do_call::h8c5f07f1fc714fb2
   8:        0x10da1d9cc - __rust_maybe_catch_panic
   9:        0x10d879f55 - _$LT$F$u20$as$u20$alloc..boxed..FnBox$LT$A$GT$$GT$::call_box::h6a96e09ff4d37bff
  10:        0x10da19c3b - std::sys::imp::thread::Thread::new::thread_start::h823686b907c11c46
  11:     0x7fffdf79f93a - _pthread_body
  12:     0x7fffdf79f886 - _pthread_start
```

Your solution would be appreciated.

Comment: Was this working before? First thing I check with weird errors like this is that the geckodriver I'm using is compatible with the version of firefox I have. I also check that all of that is compatible with the version of selenium I'm using.

Comment: Seems there is some problem with your DNS resolution. Could you set your logs to trace and show again the output?

Comment: @mrfreester No, i am creating Automation framework first time on Mac machine.

Comment: If you haven't done so already, make sure you're using the latest geckodriver and the latest version of firefox. This error looks very similar to that common issue.

Comment: @mrfreester yes i am using latest Gecko driver version 0.19.0, you can see in the logs and using Firefox 56 version which is also latest.

Comment: [This might be related](https://coderwall.com/p/ktbkea/play-framework-2-error-nodename-nor-servname-provided-or-not-known). Essentially, edit `/etc/hosts` to include localhost

Comment: @mrfreester, Yes, this was the issue. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently there is an issue [with the JDK and OSX](https://coderwall.com/p/ktbkea/play-framework-2-error-nodename-nor-servname-provided-or-not-known) where the hostname does not recognize localhost.

The solution is to add localhost to /etc/hosts

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the capabilities to the driver:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
```